# How to inspect element two exactly same tab at once?

Tags: html, css

I've been making a browser game that has a different design on mobile and desktop(using the @media rule), so I usually open two tabs on one screen.
One of them is bigger than 600px for desktop, and the other one is smaller.

What I'd like to happen is when I INSPECT ELEMENT at it, hover at the 
">div>Hello World>/div>"
those two tabs will be highlighted.

Or when I edit it to
">div class="bigger">Hello World>/div>"
the design on both tabs changes.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: Oops, sorry.
I might remove this question.